# Prove or disprove by an example that the function f is continuous at 0.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

Let $g : R → R$ be a bounded function and define $f : R→ R$ by
$f(x) = (x^2 −x)g(x)$. Prove or disprove by an example that the function
$f$ is continuous at $0$.

I am confused on how to prove this. I started by defining a function $h(x) = (x^2 - x)$ and then showing that if $h(x)$ is continuous at $0$, then $h(x)g(x)$ is as well. I'm not sure if this works though.

Comment: use the fact that $g$ is bounded, that is, there is some real $M$ such that for all real $x$, we have $|g(x)|\leq M$.

Comment: If $g$ is bounded, then there are $M$ and $N$ such that $M|x^2-x| \le |f(x)| \le N|x^2-x|$